# How to iterate over an arraylist in jsf without `<t:datatable>` or `<t:datalist>`

Tags: jsf, jsf-1.2

How to get the following result in JSF with

```
<div id="tagcloud">
    <a href="#" rel="0.1">Lorem</a>
    <a href="#" rel="2">ipsum</a>
    <a href="#" rel="3">dolor</a>
    <a href="#" rel="4">sit</a>
    <a href="#" rel="5">amet,</a>
    <a href="#" rel="6">consectetur</a>
    <a href="#" rel="7">adipisicing</a>
</div>
```

I tried `<t:datatable>` or `<t:datalist>` but both are not able to.

Comment: Just wondering, but why do you think t:datalist doesn't work?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you use Facelets, the following should do it:

```
<div id="tagcloud">
    <t:dataList value="#{backingBean.items}" var="item" layout="simple">
        <a href="#" rel="#{item.rel}">#{item.name}</a>
    </t:dataList>
</div>
```

If you're using JSP (hope not), you can replace #{item.name} with an h:outputText.

`backingBean.items` in the example points to some backing bean that returns a `List` with the values that differ for each row.

Answer (score 4):

why not use jstl

```
<c:forEach var="person" items="${people.people}">
        <tr>
          <td>${person.name}</td>
          <td>${person.age}</td>
          <td>${person.height}</td>
        </tr>
      </c:forEach>
```

or

```
<ui:repeat value="#{TableBean.perInfoAll}" var="info">
   <li> 
  <h:inputText value="#{info.id}" />
  <h:inputText value="#{info.name}" />
   </li> 
  </ui:repeat>
```